# How to change fragment's textView's text from activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, textview

I cannot find how to change fragment's `textview` from an `Activity`. I have 4 files :

```
MainActivity.java
activity_main.xml
FragmentClass.java
frag_class.xml
```

frag_class.xml has textView, I want to change the text from MainActivity.java.
FragmentClass extends Fragment, this fragment is displayed in MainActivity
FragmentClass has:

```
public void changeText(String text){
 TextView t = (TextView) this.getView().findViewById(R.id.tView);
 t.setText(text);
}
```

and in MainActivity I tried this:

```
FragmentClass fc = new FragmentClass();
fc.changeText("some text");
```

But sadly this code gives me NullPointerException at `fc.changeText("some text");`
I've also tried changing the text directly from MainActivity with:

```
 TextView t = (TextView) this.getView().findViewById(R.id.tView);
 t.setText(text);
```

which Failed.

**[EDIT]**
The full code is [here](http://pastebin.com/NQBieFLi)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@Lalit answer is correct but I see that you dont need to create a function like fragment_obj.updateTextView();. I set all my view as class level objects and was able to update the textview directly.

```
fragmentRegister.textViewLanguage.setText("hello mister how do you do");
```

Note: If you need to perform more than one action then having a function is the way to go.

Comment: I don't know if it's a good practice either, but that seems like a good alternative :). Once I even used static variables to use them in fragments... That was the easiest way of setting text, it worked for me since i was only getting like 0 to 10 short strings. Anyway, I'm sure your answer will be useful to someone, and since it's working solution here is yours +1;

Answer (score 12):

You can find the instance of Fragment by using,

For support library,

```
YourFragment fragment_obj = (YourFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().
                                              findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_id);
```

else

```
YourFragment fragment_obj = (YourFragment)getFragmentManager().
                                             findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_id);
```

Then create a method in the Fragment that updates your `TextView` and call that method using `fragment_obj` like,

`fragment_obj.updateTextView();`

Comment: ClassCastException, I don't have frament tag in my activity_main.xml, I just have LinearLayout with id frag and I use getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frag, fr).commit(); for the fragment to appear

Comment: Could that be the cause of ClassCastException?

Comment: yes thats because you are not having fragment in the xml. But as you might be adding the fragment dynamically, hopefully you will be having the instance of Fragment.

Comment: I do have instance of fragment: Fragment fr = MyFragment.newInstance(); and in MyFragment class public static Fragment newInstance(){
  MyFragment myFrag = new MyFragment();
  return myFrag;
 } How can i apply your code?

Comment: well just create a public method in your `MyFragment` class with updating the value of TextView and call it from the FragmentActivity using `myFrag.method_name();`

Comment: I know that a lot to ask, but could you please look at full code here:  http://pastebin.com/NQBieFLi

Comment: @Prabuddham is this a proper approach

Comment: `FragOne frag = (FragOne)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.textviewinfragment);`. I get the following error: 'incomaptible type`

Comment: `R.id.textview‌​infragment` is id of your Fragment or TextView?

Answer (score 12):

From `activity` to `Fragment` by `Fragment Transaction`:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main); 
    }
    public static void changeFragmentTextView(String s) {
        Fragment frag = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.yourFragment);
        ((TextView) frag.getView().findViewById(R.id.textView)).setText(s);  
    }
}
```

Comment: the text is not changing. Sorry, but what would be R.id.yourFragment if I don't have fragment tag? would it be the container in activity_main.xml that holds the fragment, or would that be the id of frag_class.xml's outter layout's id?

Comment: You must create your fragment's own layout, for example, "frag.xml"  and edit R.id.yourFragment to R.id.frag.

Comment: The fragment is created dynamically and as I have read on SO it is not possible to give an id to a dynamically created fragment. In my xml files I don't have <fragment></fragment>. I did give tag when I was creating replacing fragment, and changed your code to findFragmentByTag, but it still gives me null pointer exception. Could you please see the full code here http://pastebin.com/NQBieFLi ?

Answer (score 1):

I accomplished it other way. I have my app working like this:

After firing my app, I have MainActivity with HomeFragment created. In HomeFragment I have Button and TextView for connecting / showing state of BluetoothConnection.

In HomeFragment I implemented Handler for receiving information from BluetoothService. After receiving message I wanted to update TextView and Button text. I created public interface in HomeFragment with method that is getting String arguments for TextView and Button. In onAttach(Activity a) I created mCallback object for talking to activity.

Next step is implementing this Interface in MainActivity. From this Activity I am updating TextView and Button. Everything looks like this:

### HomeFragment.java

```
public interface ViewInterface{
    public void onViewUpdate(String buttonTxt, String txtTxt);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity a){
    super.onAttach(a);
    try{
        mCallback = (ViewInterface)a;
    }catch (ClassCastException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            switch (msg.what) {

                case MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE:

                    if(true) Log.i(CLASS_TAG, "MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGE: " + msg.arg1);
                    switch (msg.arg1) {
                        case BluetoothConnectionService.STATE_CONNECTED:

                            threadTextString = "Connected to: " + connectedDeviceName;
                            threadBtnString = "Disconnect";
                            mCallback.onViewUpdate(threadBtnString, threadTextString);
                            break;
                        case BluetoothConnectionService.STATE_CONNECTING:
                           threadTextString = "Connecting...";
                            mCallback.onViewUpdate(threadBtnString, threadTextString);
                            break;
                         case BluetoothConnectionService.STATE_NONE:

                            threadBtnString = "Connect";
                            threadTextString = "You're not connectedd";
                            mCallback.onViewUpdate(threadBtnString, threadTextString);
                            break;
}

private void updateBtn(Button btn, String data){
    btn.setText(data);
    Log.d(CLASS_TAG + "/" + "updateBtn", "Data: " + data);
}

private void updateTxt(TextView txt, String data){
    txt.setText(data);
    Log.d(CLASS_TAG + "/" + "updateTxt", "Data: " + data);

}

public void update(String buttonTxt, String txtTxt){
    this.updateTxt(connectTxt, txtTxt);
    this.updateBtn(connectButton, buttonTxt);
}
```

### MainActivity.java

```
@Override
public void onViewUpdate(String buttonTxt, String txtTxt) {
    HomeFragment homeFragment = (HomeFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frame_container);
    if(homeFragment != null){
    homeFragment.update(buttonTxt, txtTxt);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Dcrypt extends Fragment {

Button butD;
ImageButton Dcopy;
EditText getPass;
TextView txtShow;
```

use this line of code to get support of text field

```
private FragmentManager supportFragmentManager;
```