# Updating TextView within Fragment for Consistency

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am trying to build a quiz app that keeps score as the user answers questions. I'm also using Google's `ViewPager` for screen slides which employs `Fragments` to keep different individual pages (code: http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html). I have a `TextView` (`@id/txtvw_score`) that is designed to keep score across the entire quiz session. This `txtvw_score` is placed within `fragment_screen_slide_page.xml`.

The problem I'm having is that, in order to access said `TextView`, I have to do it in `ScreenSlidePageFragment`'s `onCreateView()` method. But, because Android calls this `onCreateView()` method twice for every new `Fragment`, it makes it so that the `TextView`'s score is completely outdated. For example, page 1 would display the current score, then page 2 would display page 0 (uninitialized score), then page 3 would display page 1's score, etc.

I'm using `SharedPreferences` to keep the actual score updated. I've been able to keep track of the score perfectly fine when I use the `ActionBar`. This is only for confirmation purposes though, as I don't actually want to use the `ActionBar`.

Further complicating the problem is that I can't update the TextView within the `Fragment`'s `onCreate()` method. I've also tried calling the TextView and changing it from `ScreenSlideActivity` (source: [How to change fragment's textView's text from activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16295101/how-to-change-fragments-textviews-text-from-activity)), but that ended up as `NullPointerException` no matter what I did.

So, long story short, how can I keep a `TextView`'s content consistent across all `Fragments`? (This is a significant point for me, because, in the future, I want to use a `TextView` as a display for a timer as well, and that definitely needs to stay consistent).

**EDIT (added simplified code):**

**fragment_screen_slide_page.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrlvw_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="15dp" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txtvw_score"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**ScreenSlidePageFragment.java**

```
public class ScreenSlidePageFragment extends Fragment
{
    //The argument key for the page number this fragment represents.
    public static final String ARG_PAGE = "page";
    ArrayList<String> argAnswerList = new ArrayList<String>();

    //The fragment's page number, which is set to the argument value for {@link #ARG_PAGE}.
    private int mPageNumber;
    //preferences
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs;
    SharedPreferences preferences;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    final int DEFAULT = 0;
    final int CHOSEN1 = 1;
    final int CHOSEN2 = 2;
    final int CHOSEN3 = 3;
    final int CHOSEN4 = 4;

    TextView txtvwScore;
    int questionsTotal;
    int numChosenCorrect, numChosenTotal, ratio;

    //Factory method for this fragment class. Constructs a new fragment for the given page number.
    public static ScreenSlidePageFragment create(int pageNumber)
    {
        ScreenSlidePageFragment fragment = new ScreenSlidePageFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_PAGE, pageNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public ScreenSlidePageFragment() 
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        getActivity().getActionBar().show();

        fillArgAnswerList();
        //fillAnswerList();

        mPageNumber = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PAGE);

        getPrefs();
        preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        editor = preferences.edit();

        numChosenCorrect = sharedPrefs.getInt("numChosenCorrect", DEFAULT);
        numChosenTotal = sharedPrefs.getInt("numChosenTotal", DEFAULT);
        ratio = sharedPrefs.getInt("ratio", DEFAULT);
        getActivity().getActionBar().setTitle("Score: " + numChosenCorrect + "/" + numChosenTotal + " (" + ratio + "%)");
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        //Inflate the layout containing a title and body text.
        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_screen_slide_page, container, false);

        //setting the score
        txtvwScore = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txtvw_score);

        setButtonOnClickListener();

        return rootView;
    }

    private void setButtonOnClickListener()
    {
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                    numChosenCorrect = sharedPrefs.getInt("numChosenCorrect", DEFAULT);
                    numChosenTotal = sharedPrefs.getInt("numChosenTotal", DEFAULT);
                    ratio = sharedPrefs.getInt("ratio", DEFAULT);

                    String answer = button.getText().toString();
                    if(answer.equals(correct))
                    {
                        numChosenCorrect++;
                        numChosenTotal++;
                    }
                    else
                        numChosenTotal++;

                    //update the actionBar score
                    ratio = Math.round(((float) numChosenCorrect)/((float) numChosenTotal)*100);

                    //setting the score
                    getActivity().getActionBar().setTitle("Score: " + numChosenCorrect + "/" + numChosenTotal + " (" + ratio + "%)");
                    editor.putInt("numChosenCorrect", numChosenCorrect);
                    editor.putInt("numChosenTotal", numChosenTotal);
                    editor.putInt("ratio", ratio);
                    editor.commit();
                }
            });
    }

    /**
     * Get the preferences saved.
     */
    private void getPrefs()
    {
        sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    }

    /**
     * Returns the page number represented by this fragment object.
     */
    public int getPageNumber() 
    {
        return mPageNumber;
    }
}
```

All codes have been simplified to show what the question revolves around. All removed code has been tested and they work up until this point.

Comment: I think it would be best it you supplied a little code. You're using the same code for all `Fragments` of course, but when are you saving the score in `SharedPreferences` and when are you fetching it again? You could also just pass the next score inside the `Bundle` to the next `Fragment` but I guess that could make a mess if the user is going back in the backstack.

Comment: Sure thing. Code's been added.