# Update data fragment from another activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, fragment

It's seem to be easily but I cannot find solution although i have checked at:
[How to update Android fragment from activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22751127/how-to-update-android-fragment-from-activity)
[How to change fragment's textView's text from activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16295101/how-to-change-fragments-textviews-text-from-activity)

My problem is:

I have 4 class:

- MainActivity.java
- HistoryFragment.java
- ConversationDialog.java
- CallActivity.java

In MainActivity.java, It content 2 Fragment includes HistoryFragment and ContactFragment. From HistoryFragment, I call ConversationDialog to show dialog, input to dialog and press OK to open CallActivity.

**Now, I want when I press back from CallActivity, I must update HistoryFragment with new data.**

But after research, I cannot do it.

Please help me to do this.

Comment: Could you show us what you've tried? Then maybe someone nice will help you.

Comment: Google `startActivityForResult()`!

Comment: @MuhammadBabar. I know it, but I have start activity from dialog and want to update data in fragment, I think it different ?

Comment: Activity started from dialog is basically activity started from the accompanying activity!

Comment: put the values in OnBackPressed in shared preferances in CallActivity and get the values in OnResume of previous activity and set it to fragmentHistory manager.

Comment: What if I don't want to finish current activity@TranVinhQuang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When starting the CallActivity use startActivityForResults like:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,  CallActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

Where 1 is the request code that will be used later to get back the data you are requesting.

Then in your onBackPress function in Call Activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("id","value")
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);        
finish();
```

Then do this to get your data in the previous Activity

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
if (requestCode == 1) {
     if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
      String stredittext=data.getStringExtra("id");
  }
}
```

Use the "id" is the identifier of your **value** which is **"value"**.I think now you can easily do the rest of adding your data to the history fragment using public variables.

Comment: I tried it and it OK. But I think u need edit "Then in your call Activity" to "Then in your onBackPress function in Call Activity" for easy to know.

Comment: And I have question, If I change from dialog to activity. What I would do when from MainActivity start SelectActivity and from SelectActivity I start CallActivity ?. I want to update MainActivity after press back in CallActivity and do not show SelectActivity again!

Comment: Why don't you post that as a new question in order to get a more clarity in the answer?

Answer (score 2):

The **onResume()** function of the MainActivity will be get called when you are pressing back button from CallActivity. Here the logic goes.

Do the following steps,

1.Implement a public method(i.e., updateContent()) in  HistoryFragment to update your content.

2.Get the HistoryFragment instance from onResume() of MainActivity

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = activity.getSupportFragmentManager();
HistoryFragment aFragment=fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("Place the History fragment TAG here which you have used to load before");
```

3.After getting the instance, call the relevent method through instance.

```
aFragment.updateContent()
```