# How to change TextView text fragment from the activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, textview

I repeated the answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16295101/how-to-change-fragments-textviews-text-from-activity) question , fail. 
I need to change the textView(text) that is in cardView which is located in the fragment. This is [code](http://pastebin.com/rzHqykGZ) of Fragment, i want change text in method *updateTextView*, but i have crash. 
Here's the code that I call the method with Activity

```
private void makeView(String wallPhoto, String wallText){

    Fragment fr =  TabFragment1.newInstance();
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.tab_fragment_1, fr, "tag").commit();
    TabFragment1 tabFragment1_text = (TabFragment1) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("tag");
    tabFragment1_text.updateTextView("walll");
    Log.d("", wall_text);
}
```

Crash looks like: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void pc.dd.tabhost.TabFragment1.updateTextView(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference`
Updating: 
If you do as suggested by Nfear now there is no error , but the text does not change. Something like this:

```
private void makeView(String wallPhoto, String wallText){

    Fragment fr =  TabFragment1.newInstance();
    getSupportFragmentManager(). beginTransaction().replace(R.id.tab_fragment_1, fr, "tag").commit();
    getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();

    TabFragment1 tabFragment1_text = (TabFragment1) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("tag");
    tabFragment1_text.updateTextView("walll");
    Log.d("", wall_text);
}
```

Called in to Activity asynktask like this:

```
  @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (!VKSdk.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data, new VKCallback<VKAccessToken>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(VKAccessToken res) {
            _VKLogin = true;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Login succes ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            VKRequestResponse _response = new VKRequestResponse();
            _response.execute(res);
        }
        @Override
        public void onError(VKError error) {
            _VKLogin = false;

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Login Error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }))
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
class VKRequestResponse extends AsyncTask{

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params1) {
          VKParameters _params = new VKParameters();
        _params.put(VKApiConst.COUNT, "1");
       VKRequest _vkRequest = VKApi.wall().get(_params);
        _vkRequest.executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
                    parsingFromJson(response.responseString);
                    makeView(null, wall_text);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Otvet "+response.responseString,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 super.onComplete(response);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(VKError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Ошибка "+error,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                super.onError(error);
            }

        });

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try calling `getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions()` after `commit()`

Comment: That means you want to update fragment text from activity event. am i right?

Comment: @Masum, yes, you right)

Comment: @Nfear, like this? `getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
        getSupportFragmentManager(). beginTransaction().replace(R.id.tab_fragment_1, fr, "tag").commit();`

Comment: Did you check http://stackoverflow.com/a/25543770/3965385 answer

Comment: @Nfear, i change order, no exeption now, but text not change.