# Change Fragment's TextViews's text from Activity

Tags: android

I want to change an textView's text via an Activity, but when I change by this code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private TextView txtSave;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    txtSave = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_save);;
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    TextView txtSave;
    txtSave = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_save);
    txtSave.setText("something");
}
```

}

and I got this error:

```
05-14 13:47:46.835 21949-21949/stv.wordspower E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                            Process: stv.wordspower, PID: 21949
                                                            java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                                                                at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
                                                                at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
                                                                at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
```

Can somebody add me help how can I change dynamically?
Fragment code:

```
public class ProgressFragment extends Fragment {

private View rootView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_progress, container, false);
    return rootView;
}

public static ProgressFragment newInstance() {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    ProgressFragment fragment = new ProgressFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
```

}

The textView is on the ProgressFragment. The ProgressFragment is on the MainActivity's FrameLayout.
I just want to modify the TextView's values but I can't. I have tried these [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16295101/how-to-change-fragments-textviews-text-from-activity), but one did not work.

other informations:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="stv.wordspower.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:text="@string/txtView_welcome"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:textAlignment="center" />

<Button
    android:text="@string/btn_exit"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/btn_exit"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_settings"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/btn_settings"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btn_contact"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_contact"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/btn_contact"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btn_exit"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_progress"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:text="@string/btn_progress" />

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btn_progress"
    android:layout_above="@+id/btn_settings"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:id="@+id/mainActivityFragmentLayout">
</FrameLayout>
```

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="stv.wordspower.ProgressFragment"
android:orientation="vertical">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_progresses"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/txt_progresses"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_save"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/txt_empty"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:clickable="true"/>
```

Comment: Are you using a frame layout as a container to display your fragment?

Comment: Yes, I do.  Why?

Comment: I wanted to make sure of it,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In onClick method, you can get fragment as following:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    yourFrag fragment = (yourFrag)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_id);
}
```

and in fragment, create a method to update the textView, so that we can call it using fragment object as following:

```
public void update(String s){
    textView.setText(s);
}
```

Note: This textView should be defined in your fragment.

and call this from main activity as following:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    yourFrag fragment = (yourFrag)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_id);
    fragment.update("foo");
}
```

And yes! if you are not using support library, just replace `getSupportFragmentManager()` by `getFragmentManager()`.

Comment: I tried this solution, but I can understand this part of the second row:
findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_id);
What is fragment_id and where I find?

Comment: fragment id is the id of the fragment declared in xml. @Pisti i.e ID of `<fragment>` tag.

Comment: hey it's not in manifest. It should be in one of the layout files, either in mainActivity's layout file or a separate xml layout file. As you said you are using frame layout as container, where is framelayout? `<Fragment>` must be inside it.

Comment: This is correct. You first find the fragment by fragment ID and then using that fragment instance, you call the update method inside the fragment.

Comment: Fragments are not declared in the manifest, Either you place them using a Container layout or by statically coding.

Comment: Okay! It's not here. Can you post your all layout files by editing your question?

Comment: Okay just post the layouts.

Comment: Where is textView of ID text_save?

Comment: And there is no fragment in your framelayout. It's empty.

Comment: I don't keep the fragment on the fragment layout. I call a function what looks like this:

getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .add(R.id.mainActivityFragmentLayout, ProgressFragment.newInstance())
                        .commit();
            }

And the fragment is appear on the layout.
The textView whose name is txtSave is on the Fragment.
I edited the post with fragment_progress.xml.

Comment: Okay now in your fragment_process.xml, give ID to your Linear Layout and considering it as fragment ID try my answer. I'm not sure about the results, so let me know when you are done.

Comment: Are you sure for this? In the fragment_progress.xml? Not the actitvity_main.xml's frame_layout?

Comment: It's not working.
I put the <fragment> with id in the FrameLayout of MainActivity's xml file.
The Fragment is immediately but I but in vain I click for the textView, the text is not changing BUT, I did not got error... :D